# How to return an array (Google apps script) to a HTML sidebar?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, return

I would like to return some array I made in my code.gs to my HTML sidebar and use it to fill a select, I have this so far:

Lets say I would like to use "['this', 'part', 'of', 'the', 'array', 'for', 'the', 'select']" for the html select:

code.gs

```
function ExampleArray(){
var tempArr = [['this', 'part', 'of', 'the', 'array', 'for', 'the', 'select'], []];
return tempArr;
}
```

So that is the array, I need that array to populate a html select object so I need a HTML page as well. This is my HTML code for the select:

```
<script> 
google.script.run.ExampleArray();
</script>    
<div>
         <?
            var data    =  //the array from the code.gs
         ?>
       <div class="two">
       <select id="Select1">
       <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
       <option><?!= data[i] ?></option>
       <? } ?>
       </select>
       </div>
```

How can I achieve this? :)

Comment: Why are there php tags over your script?

Comment: I can use GAS like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use successHandler or just call the script, as such:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).ExampleArray();

function onSuccess( values ){
  $.each(values, function(key, value) {   
     $('#Select1')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value)); 
  });
}
```

or

```
<?
  var data = ExampleArray();
?>
```

I always use the first method for my codes, I think it has a better control over the application. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your first method. I can see the code reaching the onSucces function (I put an alert in there and it showed) but after that nothing happends. When I: alert(values); it says: 'this', 'part', 'of', 'the', 'array', 'for', 'the', 'select'.  What goes wrong here?

Comment: That's a Jquery example, have you included it? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: I did this:
`<script src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script> 

code here </script>`

Comment: Wow I missed a $ ... I'm sorry for wasting your time man. Thanks for your solution, it works great!